# Is there a good reason not to use #pragma once in every header file?

Tags: c++, header-files, pragma

I'm new to C++ and started to organize my code like most people seem to do: in "header files" and "source files".

I'm using `#pragma once` in all those header files that contain inline functions. But I was wondering if there is a reason against simply using it in every header file?

Comment: No, unless that header has special semantics that require it be included more than once (e.g. this is common with preprocessor trickery). Of course, there is the issue that `#pragma once` isn't technically portable...

Comment: Portability would be only issue. Though most modern compilers support it.

Comment: Maybe it's better to use header guards, because of portability. Of course there is more typing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm using #pragma once in all those header files that contain inline functions

That's about the one reason that you *don't* need #pragma once.  Having multiple definitions for the same inline function is normal and expected.  And inevitable when multiple translation units #include the same header, particularly for template functions.  The linker just picks one of the definitions it finds if the compiler didn't actually inline the function.  You need #pragma once to avoid multiple definitions of the same type.